# Source for the Aseres Hadibros being set up in pairs?

Tags: midrash, parashas-yisro, aseres-hadibros

I have heard from different rebbeim that each of the aseres hadibros is linked to another, specifically in terms of the root concept of that commandment being the same as another one of the aseres hadibros. The pairs are linked as follow: 1-6, 2-7, 3-8, 4-9, 5-10. Does anyone know a source that says this, and what is, according to that source, the idea that connects each of these pairs?  (I'm a first time poster, so I apologize if the formatting isn't quite there.)

Comment: I also remember such an interpretation. +1 By the way, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887); I hope you can ask many other nice questions in the future!

Comment: See the series of videos about this by R. David Fohrman: https://www.torahmusings.com/2013/05/the-hidden-structure-of-the-ten-commandments/

Comment: here is a first (links to the rest in the article)  of a series of essays connecting the dibrot from the first tablet to the second tablet. It quotes our sages, but does not give the source -- https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2917/jewish/The-First-Commandment.htm

Answer (score 7):

Rashi ([Song 4:5](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=33&perek=4&mefaresh=rashi)) explains how each commandment on one tablet corresponds to one on the next:

> שני שדיך על שם הלוחות תאומי צביה שהם מכוונות במדה אחת וחמשה דברות על זו וחמשה על זו מכוונין דבור כנגד דבור, אנכי כנגד לא תרצח שהרוצח ממעט את הדמות של הקב"ה, לא יהיה לך כנגד לא תנאף שהזונה אחר עבודה זרה דרך אשה המנאפת תחת אישה תקח את זרים, לא תשא כנגד לא תגנוב שהגונב סופו לישבע לשקר, זכור כנגד לא תענה שהמחלל את השבת מעיד שקר בבוראו לומר שלא שבת בשבת בראשית, כבד כנגד לא תחמוד שהחומד סופו להוליד בן שמקלה אותו ומכבד למי שאינו אביו.

- "I am God" = "Don't murder" because a murderer lessens God's image (by killing someone made in God's image)
- "Have no other gods" = "Don't commit adultery" because having other gods is like a woman committing adultery
- "Don't take God's name in vain" = "Don't steal" because one who steals will end up having to swear falsely
- "Remember the Sabbath" = "Don't bear false testimony" because violating the Sabbath is testifying falsely that God didn't create the world in six days and rest on the seventh
- "Honor your father and mother" = "Don't covet" because someone who covets (someone's wife) will end up having a son who respects someone who isn't his father

Comment: According to "[הצלת רוצח מעונש מוות במדינה זרה](http://www.daat.ac.il/mishpat-ivri/skirot/253-2.htm)", footnote 1, Rashi's source is the [Mechilta on Yitro (מסכת דבחדש)](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=2&perek=20&mefaresh=mehilta), section 8, s.v "כיצד נתנו עשרת הדברות".

Comment: The [Judaica Press translation of Rashi on Song of Songs 4:5](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16448#v=5&showrashi=true).

Answer (score 3):

Ramban (Exodus 20:13) mentions that the Ten Commandments are split between the two tablets, with the first five paralleling the latter five, but he does not discuss the specific links.

> והנראה במכתב הלוחות שהיו החמש ראשונות בלוח אחד שהם כבוד הבורא כמו
>   שהזכרתי והחמש השניות בלוח אחד שיהיו חמש כנגד חמש כענין שהזכירו בספר
>   יצירה בעשר ספירות בלי מה כמספר עשר אצבעות חמש כנגד חמש וברית יחיד
>   מכוונת באמצע ומזה יתברר לך למה היו שתים כי עד כבד את אביך הוא כנגד
>   תורה שבכתב, ומכאן ואילך כנגד תורה שבעל פה ונראה שלזה רמזו רבותינו ז"ל
>   שאמרו שתי לוחות כנגד שמים וארץ וכנגד חתן וכלה וכנגד שני שושבינין וכנגד
>   שני עולמים וכל זה רמז אחד והמשכיל יבין הסוד

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP recognizes this but wants to know the details of the connections.

Comment: @sabbahillel "Does anyone know a source that says this"

Comment: *what is, according to that source, the idea that connects each of these pairs?* See the other answer. Also the citation from the Ramban is that they are split five and five, but he does not say that each one on one side is connected to the specific one on the other side.